# jquery menucool slider not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am not an expert in javascript or jQuery and facing problem working with jQuery slider.

The slider is working well in the demo site and i have implemented it well but for some reason its not working. in debug i got only error that is reference error, don't understand what is the reason for this.

This the slider I am using: http://www.menucool.com/jquery-slider

I tried using both pure javascript version and jQuery version. now presently jQuery version is implemented. I don't know why its not working.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

its very simple 
in 
Menucool jQuery Slider v2012.11.22

find the `a.replace(/(?:.*\.)?(\w)([\w\-])?[^.]*(\w)\.[^.]*$/,"$1$3$2")` in jquery-slider.js file

change to `a.replace("","$1$3$2")`

and enjoy

Comment: good one. but i want to know how did you find this in minified js :) bulls eye....

Comment: Is there any way to make it on v2013.12.1 ?

Comment: @biju-b-adoor  I really wonder that how did you know that ? :)

Answer (score 5):

For the last version of menucool just replace:

```
return "b" + a + b[1] + c(b[0]) + c(b[2])
```

for

```
return "mylicense"
```

don't forget that te var license must be:

```
license: "mylicense"
```

It worked for me :).

Comment: It is not working for me! Unexpected end of input error

Answer (score 4):

**For the last version of menucool just replace:**

**Find the**

```
vb=function(d,c){for(var b=[],a=0;a<d[e];a++)b[b[e]]=String[kb](d[Z](a)-(c?c:3));return b.join("")},
```

**From slider js file and Replace with**

```
vb=function(d,c){return " "},
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all I would like to thanks **bijub** for providing valuable answer.
But it doesn't work with latest versions of query-slider.js file. For latest versions try these.
Its work for me.

find the code "a.replace(/(?:.*.)?(\w)([\w-])?[^.]*(\w).[^.]*$/,"$1$3$2")" in jquery-slider.js file.

replace the "$1$3$2" with your url.

example :

```
a.replace(/(?:.*\.)?(\w)([\w\-])?[^.]*(\w)\.[^.]*$/,a)
```

or

```
a.replace(/(?:.*\.)?(\w)([\w\-])?[^.]*(\w)\.[^.]*$/,"http://www.mywebsite.com")
```

Enjoy :D

Comment: Which version query-slider.js does your solution work for? Does it work for all versions? Take into account that the answers remain in the site for future reference.

Comment: I tested this on **v2013.3.18**.

Answer (score 2):

I just manage to fix the v2016.12.29 version.
Find this piece of code:

```
yb=function(d,c){for(var b=[],a=0;a<d[e];a++)b[b[e]]=String[nb](d[Z](a)-(c?c:3));return b.join("")}
```

And insert this little if inside: `if (b.join("")=="Ninja Slider trial version") return "";`

Like this:

```
yb=function(d,c){for(var b=[],a=0;a<d[e];a++)b[b[e]]=String[nb](d[Z](a)-(c?c:3)); if (b.join("")=="Ninja Slider trial version") return "";return b.join("")}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to put your slider.js after the jquery.js file

Answer (score 1):

OK sorry, its because of licensing, it works well in local host but in server it needs to be purchased. otherwise it wont work;

Comment: @Faizan did you find any workaround solution?I have same problem.It says  " Thumbnail Slider trial version"  I can not delete this

Answer (score 0):

This is old... however i faced this problem and i dont believe the price is fair so i have no problems with tricking it

ThumbnailSlider Slider v2015.10.26

find in thumbnail-slider.js

```js
apply(this, [a, Y, b, Qb, wb, o, vb, xb, document, m]
```

and replace with

```js
apply(this, [a, Y, b, Qb, wb, o, vb, xb, o, m]
```