# How to remove MenuCool Trial version for localhost for the lastest version v2015.10.26.

Tags: slider

I am trying to make the slider work in my local machine either using http://localhost/thumbnail-slider or using http://127.0.0.1/thumbnail-slider.  In both the cases I am getting the message occasionally "Thumbnail Slider trial version".

I tried all the steps in the below url with no success in any of the solution for the version v2015.10.26
[jquery menucool slider not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114202/jquery-menucool-slider-not-working)

Comment: Ok thanks I have found solution.

Comment: how you got the solution

Comment: can you please share your solution- @JanakiramanBalakrishnan

Comment: @JanakiramanBalakrishnan kindly share the solution.

Answer (score 14):

Try this

**Find the**

```
vb=function(d,c){for(var b=[],a=0;a<d[e];a++)b[b[e]]=String[kb](d[Z](a)-(c?c:3));return b.join("")},
```

**From slider js file and Replace with**

```
vb=function(d,c){return " "},
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this, It worked for `ThumbnailSlider Slider v2015.10.26.`

```
vb = function (d, c) {
                for (var b = [], a = 0; a < d[e]; a++)
                    b[b[e]] = String[kb](d[Z](a) - (c ? c : 3));
                if (b.join("") == "Thumbnail Slider trial version")
                    return "";
                return b.join("")
            },
```

Answer (score 4):

For Ninja Slider v2016.12.29

It's both of the answers above:

> find the `a.replace(/(?:..)?(\w)([\w-])?[^.](\w).[^.]*$/,"$1$3$2")` in jquery-slider.js file
>
> change to `a.replace("","$1$3$2")`

AND

```
yb = function (d, c) {
            for (var b = [], a = 0; a < d[e]; a++)
                b[b[e]] = String[nb](d[Z](a) - (c ? c : 3));
            if (b.join("") == "Ninja Slider trial version")
                return "";
            return b.join("")
        },
```

Although I had to make it

```
yb = function (d, c) {
        for (var b = [], a = 0; a < d[e]; a++)
            b[b[e]] = String[nb](d[ab](a) - (c ? c : 3));
        if (b.join("") == "Ninja Slider trial version")
            return "";
        return b.join("")
    },
```

Notice `d[Z]` was changed to `d[ab]`.

P.S.  I tried buying the $29 license, but the website won't let the order go through.

Comment: It worked, same I tried to buy but the order didn't go through!

Comment: it removes the text, but it interferes with the logic. Clicking next/prev doesn't work properly anymore

Answer (score 1):

its very simple

find the

```
return a.replace(/(?:.*\.)?(\w)([\w\-])?[^.]*(\w)\.[^.]*$/, "$1$3$2")
```

in js file

change to `return null;`

and enjoy

Answer (score 0):

**You need to take four steps**

1. Find this code for Ninja slider Js file

`return a.replace(/(?:.*\.)?(\w)([\w\-])?[^.]*(\w)\.[^.]*$/,"$1$3$2")`

replace to:

`return null`

2. find code  with string "www."

`Sb=function(a){var b=Yb(document.domain.replace("www.",""));`

change to:

`Sb=function(a){var b=Yb(document.domain.replace("",""));`

delete the word "www."

3. find code

`Ab=["$1$2$3","$1$2$3","$1$24","$1$23","$1$22"]`

delete string value inside bracket:

`Ab=[]`

4. find code

`apply(this,[a,Y,b,Qb,wb,o,vb,xb,document,m]`

(or `apply(this,[a,ab,g,Tb,zb,i,yb,Ab,document,y])` )

replace with

`apply(this, [a, Y, b, Qb, wb, o, vb, xb, o, m]`

(or `apply(this,[a,ab,g,Tb,zb,i,yb,Ab,i,y])` )

change the "document" with 6th var

Answer (score -1):

find the a.replace(/(?:.*.)?(\w)([\w-])?[^.]*(\w).[^.]*$/,"$1$3$2") in jquery-slider.js file

change to a.replace("","$1$3$2")

Answer (score -1):

Find and replace in ninja-slider.js

Worked for `Ninja Slider v2016.12.29`

```
yb = function (d, c) {
            for (var b = [], a = 0; a < d[e]; a++)
                b[b[e]] = String[nb](d[Z](a) - (c ? c : 3));
            if (b.join("") == "Ninja Slider trial version")
                return "";
            return b.join("")
        },
```

Hope it helps someone. :)

Answer (score -1):

I have found a solution using CSS.
Give a unique class to the parent `div` and then use `color:transparent;`

Answer (score -2):

just do text-indent -9999px on text div.

Comment: Please elaborate on how this answers the question.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an answer really needs to demonstrate the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead (once you have earnt that privilege).

Comment: Sorry guys, i was in short time. Just try help. 
Next time i'll pay more attention.